# Convert a variable sized numpy array to Tensorflow Tensors

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying Tensorflow 2.0 alpha preview and was testing the Eager execution .
My doubt is that if you have a numpy array of variable size in middle like

```
input.shape
(10,)

input[0].shape
(109, 16)

input[1].shape
(266, 16)
```

and so on for the rest of the array , how does one eagerly convert them to tensors.

when I try

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(input)
```

or

```
tf.Variable(input)
```

I get

> ValueError: Failed to convert numpy ndarray to a Tensor (Unable to get
>   element as bytes.).

Converting each sub-array works , but because the sub-array size isn't same , tf.stack doesn't work.

Any help or suggestions ?

Comment: I think you may want to use a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensors).

Comment: I tried ragged  , but still the same error. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: You `input` appears to be a NumPy array of objects, maybe try converting it to a list instead (`list(input)`)?

Comment: @jdehesa Ragged tensors using lists requires me to make a list of lists , something I wouldnt like to do with large sizes of my array .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happening to me in eager as well. Looking at the [docs here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) , I ended up trying

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(input, dtype=tf.float32)
```

And that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you can make lists of arrays, then [`tf.ragged.stack`](https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/stack) should do it. You can use it like this for example:

```
tf.ragged.stack([tf.convert_to_tensor(arr) for arr in arrays], axis=0)
```

This will stack uneven sized arrays into a [`RaggedTensor`](https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way to work with this is to use lists of lists and then convert them to ragged tensors, since numpy doesnt support ragged arrays very well. Will Update if I find anything new